# Best practice to verify Optional using hamcrest

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, testing, guava

This test is not working

```
assertThat(bundle.getMyObj(), equalTo(Optional.absent()));
```

---

At the beginning I just use a common object. (Didn't use optional<> yet)

```
private MyObj myObj;
```

The test will look like this

```
assertThat(myBundle.getMyObj(), nullValue());
```

The I change myObj to

```
private Optional<MyObj> myObj = Optional.absent();
```

Then I changed my test to

```
assertThat(bundle.getTracking(), equalTo(Optional.absent()));
```

Then I got an error

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: <Optional.absent()>
     but: was <Optional.of(com.my.package.MyObj@2a9627bc)>
Expected :<Optional.absent()>

Actual   :<Optional.of(com.my.package.MyObj@2a9627bc)>
```

I also try this code below but got compile error

```
assertThat(myBundle.getMyObj(), equalTo(Optional.of(MyObj)));
```

Comment: You can check if optional `isEmpty()` or not

Comment: is that the best practice?

Comment: It is more verbose and shorter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: <Optional.absent()>
but: was <Optional.of(com.my.package.MyObj@2a9627bc)>
Expected :<Optional.absent()>
Actual   :<Optional.of(com.my.package.MyObj@2a9627bc)>
```

Says that your `Optional` object is not empty. It seems that `bundle.getTracking()` is returning **not empty** optional.

Also, if you want check if optional is empty or not in your test, I recommend you to use method `isPresent()`.

Instead of `assertThat(bundle.getTracking(), equalTo(Optional.absent()))` just use `assertTrue(bundle.getTracking().isPresent())`

Comment: right now I verify nonNull() and try to verify it specifically so I add assertequalTo(Optional.absent()) and then verify .isPresent().. may be I shouldn't verify equalTo(Optional.absent())

Answer (score 0):

Best practice using JUnit5:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;
assertTrue(myOptional.isPresent());
```